# how beforeEach works in jasmine without done

Tags: jasmine, angular-test

Looking at the code generated by `angular cli`, the `beforeEach` method uses `async` but doesn't call `done()`. How does it work then? Isn't calling `done` mandatory when using `async`?

```
beforeEach(async(() => { //async
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule,RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes), ReactiveFormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents(); 
  }));//done not called

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageNotFoundComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `done()` is the last callback an async function should call, calling it between will throw an error.

Have a look at this guide https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async , it describes about `done()` and it should be handled.